# Running multiple migrations in the same command

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, migration, symfony5

I have a multi-tenant Symfony 5 application that consists in a general database which is responsible with global data and a dynamic amount of tenant databases, using the same schema among them, that are responsible with tenant specific data storage.

In total I have 2 entity managers, `default` that is connected to the general database and `tenant` that uses a wrapper (`MultiDbConnectionWrapper`) that can switch between any of the tenants databases.

#### config/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_CORE)%'
            tenant:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_TENANT)%'
                wrapper_class: App\Dbal\MultiDbConnectionWrapper
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    Core:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Core'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Core'
                        alias: Core
            tenant:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    Tenant:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Tenant'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Tenant'
                        alias: tenant
```

For each EM, I'm using a different directory for migrations as well as a different migration config file/

#### config/migrations/tenant_migrations.yaml

```
migrations_paths:
    'TenantMigrations': 'migrations/tenant'
em: 'tenant'
```

#### config/migrations/core_migrations.yaml

```
migrations_paths:
  'CoreMigrations': 'migrations/core'
em: 'default'
```

My issue is that I'm trying to create a command that will cycle through all of the tenants databases and will run the migrations on each one. In my main database I have a table called `tenants` where I have stored the name of that tenant database.

To do so, I created the following command:

#### src/Command/MigrateTenantsCommand.php

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $tenants = $this->tenantRepository->findAll();
        $connection = $this->tenantEntityManager->getConnection();

        foreach ($tenants as $tenant){
            $db = $tenant->getDatabaseUuid();
            $connection->selectDatabase($db);

            $this->getApplication()
                ->find('doctrine:migrations:migrate')
                ->run(new ArrayInput([
                    '--configuration' => 'config/migrations/tenant_migrations.yaml',
                    '--no-interaction' => true
                ]),$output);
        }


        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```

The problem is that if I have at least 2 tenants stored in database and the command `doctrine:migrations:migrate` has to run twice, at the second run it throws the following error:

```
In FrozenDependencies.php line 13:
                                                             
  The dependencies are frozen and cannot be edited anymore.
```

From what I've tried it seems that somehow it is not related to the fact that I'm changing databases at `$connection->selectDatabase($db);`, but the fact that I cannot run twice the `doctrine:migrations:migrate` inside a command.

I've tried running also the following command and I received the same error:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $this->getApplication()
            ->find('doctrine:migrations:migrate')
            ->run(new ArrayInput([
                '--configuration' => 'config/migrations/core_migrations.yaml'
            ]),$output);
        $this->getApplication()
            ->find('doctrine:migrations:migrate')
            ->run(new ArrayInput([
                '--configuration' => 'config/migrations/core_migrations.yaml'
            ]),$output);
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```

Anyone got any ideea why this happens? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How I solved the issue:

It seems that `doctrine:migrations:migrate` locks itself in order to prevent multiple runs from the same command.

In order to bypass this, we can run the command inside a different process at each loop.

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $companies = $this->companyRepository->findAll();
        foreach ($companies as $company){
            $db = $company->getDatabaseUuid();
            $connection = $this->tenantEntityManager->getConnection();
            $connection->selectDatabase($db);
            $process = new Process([
                "bin/console",
                "doctrine:migrations:migrate",
                "--configuration=config/migrations/tenant_migrations.yaml",
                "--em=tenant",
            ]);
            $process->run();
            if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
            }
            echo $process->getOutput();
        }
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```

This will lead to a second problem.
Since we run `$connection->selectDatabase($db);` in the current command process, but `doctrine:migrations:migrate` inside a new process, the entity manager won't have the database selected.

The solution was to create 2 commands as follows:

- `migrate:single-tenant` command that can recieve a `--db` parameter and runs `doctrine:migrations:migrate` the default way
- `migrate:tenants` command that get all the databases and run `migrate:single-tenant --db=$db`  as a new process in a loop

This way we set the database on the same process as the execution of `doctrine:migrations:migrate` and in the same time we keep only one migration per process

Here are the final commands

#### migrate:single-tenant

```
protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this
            ->addOption('db', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Database selection')
        ;
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
        $db = $input->getOption('db');
        if (!$db) {
            $io->error('"--db" option missing');
            return Command::FAILURE;
        }
        $connection = $this->tenantEntityManager->getConnection();
        $connection->selectDatabase($db);
        $this->getApplication()
            ->find('doctrine:migrations:migrate')
            ->run(new ArrayInput([
                '--configuration' => 'config/migrations/tenant_migrations.yaml',
                '--em' => 'tenant'
            ]),$output);
        $io->success("$db migrated succesfully");
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```

#### migrate:tenants

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $companies = $this->companyRepository->findAll();
        foreach ($companies as $company){
            $db = $company->getDatabaseUuid();
            $process = new Process([
                "bin/console",
                "migrate:single-tenant",
                "--db=$db",
            ]);
            $process->run();
            if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
            }
            echo $process->getOutput();
        }
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```